# VB.net deleting row from DT

Tags: vb.net, datatable, delete-row

I have the below code which works fine, although I want it to only delete the row if the whole row is empty. At the moment if there is no text in the first column it deletes the row even though there maybe text in the other columns.

Also want to trim the text as sometimes there are spaces in the columns with no text. this will ensure that blank rows are deleted.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
For i As Integer = dt.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
Dim row As DataRow = dt.Rows(i)
If row.Item(0) Is Nothing Then
   dt.Rows.Remove(row)
ElseIf row.Item(0).ToString.Trim = "" Then
   dt.Rows.Remove(row)
End If
```

Next

Comment: Are you aware that you're not actually deleting a record there?  That is removing the row from the `DataRowCollection` as though it was never added, so nothing can or will be deleted from the database as a result.

Comment: You obviously already know how to test one field.  If you want to test all fields then go ahead.  It will be exactly the same for each filed as for the one you're already doing.  If you already know how to take a steps, do you need someone to tell you how to walk down the street?  Of course not, because it's just one step multiple times.  The same goes here.

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the rows from just a datatable not from database.
Below code could help you.

```
Dim valuesarr As String = String.Empty
For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim lst As New List(Of Object)(dt.Rows(i).ItemArray)
    For Each s As Object In lst
        valuesarr &= s.ToString 'can use trim here if you want to delete spaces
    Next
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(valuesarr) Then
        'Remove row here, this row do not have any value
        dt.Rows(i).Remove()
    End If
Next
```